# Does the Zoom app work well with the M2 chip?

Tags: mac-mini, zoom

I want to buy the M2 Mini plus Studio Display but saw messages on the Zoom site that some were having trouble running Zoom on the Mini with M2 chip. Can anyone here reassure me? Please answer only if you use the Zoom app on an Mac M2 Mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have an M2 Mini, and Zoom works fine.

If you read the forums of the internet: some people are having problems with every single application and computer process. Photoshop, Word, Zoom, Affinity Publisher, Logic, Pages, iMovie, etc, etc, etc. Printing also doesn't work. ;-)

What you need to do is see if the developers of Zoom have confirmed that the problem has been identified.

I'd also be very surprised if there were specific problems on the M2 that the M1 wasn't having. They are identical, as far as software knows.

Even if there is a problem with Zoom on M2 Macs, then it's likely to be fixed by a future software update fairly quickly -- either to Zoom, or to the OS -- and it certainly shouldn't affect your purchase decision significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to Zooming on the M2 Mini. It also works flawlessly and smoothly on M2 Air and M1 mini. Any Apple Silicon Mac is overpowered for that sort of program. Zoom has decent support if you should have a software / configuration issue you can't solve and Apple will support it for FaceTime video so you'll know you have a good Mac and support for video and sound conferencing if you choose to purchase.

There's really no issue I can think of that matters M1 / M2 / max or plain or ultra where something doesn't work on the consumer app space. Having better performance than the M1 won't be an issue if you get the M2 mini.

Comment: But the OP is looking for a M2 Mini. Did I misunderstood or you forgot to talk about this model ("works flawlessly and smoothly on M2 Air and M1 mini")?

Comment: @Thinkr MacOS is identical across every model; and there are no functional differences between M1 and M2 CPUs. Apart from specific hardware driver bugs, there are very few bugs likely to affect M2 Minis but not M2 MBAs.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Thank you for answering. FaceTime would NOT be at all helpful for my work or volunteering, but the first answer is from someone using Zoom on an M2 mini so I should be OK to proceed with the purchase.

Comment: The intent was that you will know the camera can function and not get the run around from either Zoom or Apple if you ran into an issue. Not to convince you to change ecosystems @JaneGarthson

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Thinkr - I haven't seen a single issue on any of the Apple Silicon models yet that makes any difference in the functioning of consumer software. Have you detected or seen one where it matters M1 / Max / Ultra / M2 or form factor?

Comment: @bmike no I haven't but I wanted to be sure that you haven't missed a case. :)

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented. I've gone ahead with the purchase and am now waiting eagerly - apparently the M2 mini is out of stock for a week or so. The studio display has already shipped, they say.

Comment: Congratulations @JaneGarthson I hope you find a ton of amazing things to do with your new kit.